# Copy a list of pdf files in R and Dynamically rename while pasting

Tags: r, file

Want to copy  FS.pdf files from one folder to other folder in R , but while pasting the pdf files I want to rename the files to FS_1.pdf , FS_2.pdf like wise?

```
parent.folder<-"C:/Users/Sam/Big Doc Classification/RAW DATA"
sub.folders1 <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=TRUE)[-1]
new_folder <- "C:/Users/Sam/Big Doc Classification/TAX"
list_of_files <- list.files(sub.folders1, "FS.pdf$")
list_of_files


list_of_files
[1] "FS.pdf" "FS.pdf" "FS.pdf" "FS.pdf" "FS.pdf"

file.copy(file.path(parent.folder,list_of_files), new_folder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many sub folders you have, you might find it easier to copy all of the PDF files you have to the same directory and then rename them using a loop:

```
# Directory containing all files
  parent.folder<-"C:/Users/Sam/Big Doc Classification/RAW DATA"

# Return a list of the existing PDF names in parent.folder:
  list_of_files <- list.files(parent.folder, 
                       pattern = "*.pdf", full.names = TRUE)
# Rename all files
  for(i in 1:length(list_of_files)){
            file.rename(list_of_files[i], paste0("FS", i, ".pdf"))
  }
```